# Is there something special I need to do to ensure the AAD Connect synchronized extension attribute is included in the token claims?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a query about adding extension claims to an idToken using MSAL.JS 1.1.3 – it seems to work where an extension attribute was [added into an AAD application](https://objectsharp.com/blog/azure-ad-connect-populating-the-optional-claims-section-of-an-application-manifest-using-powershell) but not via AAD Connect.

**Is there something I need to do to ensure the AAD Connect synchronized extension attribute is included in the token?**

I have the following setup with 2 extension attributes (extension_{id}*customOptionalclaimApplicationUserCode (added in AAD) and extension*{id}_stuExtensionAttriibute1 (added to AAD via AAD Connect from on-prem AD):
[PowerShell displaying attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnx0i.png)

Customer wants to use manifest so I set [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03n5a.jpg) up.

The decoded token only includes extn.CustomOptionalClaimApplicationUserCode as per [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9anT.jpg)

The customer prefers to use manifest optional claims [as per the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#optional-claims-example) for least privilege per application instead of claims mapping policy.

To repeat the question: **Is there something special I need to do to ensure the AAD Connect synchronized extension attribute is included in the token claims?**

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, `extension_{id}_customOptionalclaimApplicationUserCode` 's id is different from `extension_{id}_stuExtensionAttriibute1`'s id.

One of the two ids is the id of the app itself. The other one is the app id used by AD Connect.

Now, the fact is that, from the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions#register-an-extension--) , one extension attribute is lying on an application.

However, you can only get the extension claim value from its application in a token. **In other words, the resource id should be the same as the id in the extension, then you can get the extension value.** For more details, you may refer to: [Configuring optional claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-optional-claims)

[image]

So, the result you got is expected. The extension synced from on premise will not be included in token.

Comment: Thanks @Jack - that makes sense. Would i need to request a token for the AAD Connect ID? That doesn't make sense to me for end users.

Comment: No. I think the better way is to call the AAD Graph API to get the user's detailed information which contains all the extension value. Here is a tutorial for [Reading an extension value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions#read-an-extension-value--)